# Identify Process Holding Lock on File

Tags: linux, unix

I have a file named `parent.control` i just create it in my program, its just a text file.
Sometimes other processes open and lock this file. I would like to identify which process(es) has locked it. Is this possible? I'm using Ubuntu but looking for a cross *nix solution.

Comment: "Sometimes other processes open and lock this file". How do you know this is the case? Do you get an error message about that?

Comment: n.m. yes i get an error on trying to open the file for reading/writing. Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch I will try it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
lsof | grep "parent.control"
```

or

```
fuser parent.control
```

Comment: Thank you! Ill test and get report back!

Comment: Worked thank you very much!!! i actually didn't do grep i just did `lsof /home/noi/Desktop/parent.control` why did you recommend ` | "parent.control"` what does that do?

Comment: @Noitidart If you know the full path to the file, you can do as you did, and just pass the filename to `lsof`. If you just know part of it (say you know it contains `parent`), you can use `lsof` to list all open files, and then pipe the output through `grep "parent"` to list the lines of output that contain `parent`.